# How to lock trackpad in blackberry using jquery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, blackberry, ide

Is there a way to block my users to use the trackpad in blackberry by locking the trackpad for a certain time ??

I need to do it using Jquery...

I have implied the plugin [JqueryblockUI](http://www.malsup.com/jquery/block/) using jquery but i jus displays the loading message but never blocks the User actions especially "trackpad"..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the [JqueryblockUI](http://malsup.com/jquery/block/) plugin by blockint the mousemove event..

or the plugin itself locks the UI from the user.. User can jus scroll using the trackpad but click events will be blocked..!